# Write a js script in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a script from another website using jQuery then document.write it

here is my code

```
var url = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js";
var dam = $.getScript(url);
document.write(dam);
```

But this doesn't work!!
all what I get on the page is `[object Object]`

Can this be achieved without XHR?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snygv469/)

Comment: Why not include the script using the url? Why do you want to write it to a div?

Comment: Just want to know if someone can achieve this :) , it's really important to me.

Comment: That is the expected behviour. `$.getScript` returns an object.

Comment: Well , is there a way to type content in a file in a div without using XMLHttpRequest ?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to hack something.

Comment: Is it possible ? @KiranVarsani

Comment: Are you trying to get the code from the CDN then print it in a `div`?

Comment: I am trying to get the HTTP request response and put it in a div , is that possible ?

Comment: I think that it would be impossible to get response without requesting through `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Before adding a bounty to your question, at least go through the motion of making it a real question. No one has any real idea as to what you're actually after. (My intuition is that this is an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Please clean up your question. See to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for further reference.

Comment: AFAIK $.getScript(url) gets the script and executes it, you will have access to the VARIABLES in the script but not the source itself.

Comment: @JohnroePauloCañamaque ,What if I get response without XHR ?

Comment: @Jobst , Thank you. I believe your comment is the most helpful here.

Comment: So, @MahmoudGamal, what is it that you're trying to do? Your question is unclear. Please elaborate.

Comment: Well you can display external javascript content in a div on some browsers (like chrome), yet you may not really access it.

Comment: This definitely smacks of an XY question. Could the poster provide any type of background about why the artificial constraints he's imposed are practical in some way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use `document.write`, [it does not do what you think it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write). What it **does not do** is write some data at the end of the document. What it does *instead*, is pipe data into the current write stream. And if there is no write stream, it will make a new one, resetting the document's content. So calling document.write(dam) means you just wiped your document. `document.write` is a low level JS function from an earlier era of JavaScript, **don't use it**.

Instead, you want to use modern DOM manipulation functions, so in jQuery, that's stuff like:

```
$(document.head).append($("<script>").attr("src", url));
```

where

```
$("<script>")
```

builds a new script element,

```
$(...).attr("src", url)
```

sets the "src" attribute to what you need it to be, and:

```
$(document.head).append(...)
```

or

```
$(document.body).append(...)
```

to get the script loaded into your document. If it's a plain script with `src` attribute, it can basically go anywhere, and if it's a script with text content that should run, you can only make that happen through `document.head`.

Although if it's *just* a script you need to load in and run, you can use `getScript`, but then you don't need to do anything else, it's just:

```
var url = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js";
jQuery.getScript(url);
```

Done, jQuery will load the script and execute it. Nothing gets returned.

Of course, the code you're showing is loading jQuery, using jQuery, so that's kind of super-odd. If you just want to load jQuery on your page, obviously you just use HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="http://https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

with the script load at the end so the script load doesn't block your page. And then finally: why on earth are we loading jQuery version 1.x instead of 2.x? (if you need to support IE8: that's not even supported by Microsoft anymore, so you probably don't need to).

And finally, if we don't want to load the script, but we really just want its content, as plain text, there's only a million answers on Stackoverflow already that tell you how to do that. With jQuery, that's:

```
$.get("http://https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js", function(data) {
  $(document.body).append($("div").text(data));
});
```

Comment: Thanks , but executing the script on the page is not my goal!. I want to get the script content and put it a div (USING JAVASCRIPT - NO XHR) , is that possible ?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal how do you suppose you fetch a script on a remote server without XHR?

Comment: if you need to get the file contents, you need to first get the file, which requires setting up an XHR transfer. Wanting to use "javascript, but no XHR" is like saying you need a car that can go fast, but has no wheels. You're going to need XHR, and jQuery's functions for getting file content use XHR behind the scenes (answer updated)

Answer (score 4):

> executing the script on the page is not my goal!. I want to get the
>   script content and put it a div (USING JAVASCRIPT - NO XHR) , is that
>   possible ?

Try utilizing an `<iframe>` element

```html
<div>
  <iframe width="500" height="250" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/snygv469/3/

Answer (score 0):

Make it easier... use my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/wwwfzya7/1/

I used javascript to create an HTML element

```
var url = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js";

var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT"); //creates: <script></script>
script.src = url; //creates: <script src="long_jquery_url.js"></script>

document.body.appendChild(script); //adds the javascript-object/html-element to the page.!!!
```

Comment: This will return `[object HTMLScriptElement]`

Comment: THAT IS BECAUSE YOU ARE USING DOCUMENT.WRITE()

Comment: use document.body.appendChild(script)

Comment: Nothing happens when using `document.body.appendChild(script);` .  I have checked your fiddle and it's not working there also!

Comment: try document.head.appendChild(script) or maybe document.appendChild(script).. but don't do it inside of JSFiddle.. JSFiddle has weird limitations, so do it separately in a local file, not on JSFIddle.

Comment: I have already tried this , but still not working.
Thank you , I appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way, it can fix your problems.

```
$.get( "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js", function( data ) {  
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: this sends an XMLHttpRequest , not a solution!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" ></script>
```

Then an AJAX call, but it pulls data from CACHE. It looks like an AJAX but when `<script>` is added file goes in cache, then read from cache in the ajax. In cases where it is not stored in cache read it using normal AJAX.

```
jQuery.cachedScript = function(url, options) {
    // Allow user to set any option except for dataType, cache, and url
    options = $.extend(options || {}, {
        dataType: "text",
        cache: true,
        url: url
    });
    // Use $.ajax() since it is more flexible than $.getScript
    // Return the jqXHR object so we can chain callbacks
    return jQuery.ajax(options);
};
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    // Usage
    $.cachedScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js").done(function(script, textStatus) {
        console.log(script);
    });
});
```

**Normal Solution**

If you are ready to use AJAX look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/8tztns7p/2/)

Answer (score 0):

**How to fetch content of remote file and paste it on your document and execute that `js` code**

I guess you want to get content written on remote file and want to write that content in your HTML. to do this you can use `load()` function.

**To do this follow the following steps:**

**1.** Create a file `index.html` Write the following code in it:

```
 <pre id="remote_script"></pre>


 <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        //var url = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js";
        var url = "remote_script.html";/* For testing*/
        $('#remote_script').load(url,function(){
            eval($('#remote_script').text()); /* to execute the code pasted in #remote_script*/
        });

    });
    </script>
```

**2.** Create another file `remote_script.html` for testing write `alert('a');` in it without any `<script>` tag and run the above code.